# Subviews of NSVisualEffectView has black background

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, subview, nsvisualeffectview

The two LevelIndicators have a black opaque background, which are the sub views of a NSVisualEffectView ,, how to make the background translucent ?

[image]

Comment: did you come up with any solution to this problem? I've got the same problem.

Comment: No, I did not, hoping for some help from the community !